# Question about logic

Tags: logic

[image]

I’m trying to solve some basic statistics problems (I want to start studying next semester, and so in ordert to prepare I started learning and downloaded some practice exams.

With most logic questions i seem to do well, but with the problem below i seem to miss a key concept.

The question in German just askes how many of the statements below are true.

My first problem.
Is the weird symbol in de second and third term a existential quantifier?
I cant find a symbol in my math books, not even in a book on logic.

So assuming it is an existential quantifier:

My problems with the second and third term seems to be that i don’t understand the existial quantifier as well as I assumed.

It means that there is at least one z that does belong to x.
Which does also mean that there may be a z that does not belong to z.
But how can I than say that difference of y and z is greater than 2?

I have the same problem with the third term.

I hope you can help as I really seem to not get the basic principle.

Many thanks

Petra

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. To your first question, I agree with you. It seems to be a strange font face for `∃`.
2. The second question should read "For each y in x, there is a z in x, for which the equation holds" So a basic way to test is to see:

   - for y=2, is there a z, so that |2 - z| > 2? Well, z=6 satisfies the condition.
   - Same holds for y=1, z=6
   - For y=6, you have a reciprocal situation, thus z=1 and z=2 are solutions.

Thus for all y you have at least one z that satisfies the condition.

3.The order of the quantifiers in the third equation is reverse, so it would read "There is a y in x, so that all z in x satisfy the condition. If your y=6, then e.g. z=1 does not satisfy the condition. Otherwise, z=6 does not satisfy it. Thus it is false.

Comment: I think the $\forall$ is a V with a dash typed over it, and the $\exists$ is a ] with a dash typed before it.  Perhaps the text generation software did not support the regular characters - this kind of Frankenstein symbolism was more common with typewriters. This example is particularly ugly.

Comment: Many thanks for your answer, its actually pretty logic ( ;) ) i should have been able to see it that way myself. Nonetheless, i tried to solve other questions of a similar type and am now able to grasp them and solve them. It is sometimes not that easy to study on your own bc sometimes just a little hint can do so much to see the solution. :) Thanks